# Creating an R wordcloud for a dataframe with a "word" and "count" column (NOVICE)

Tags: r, word-cloud

I'm quite new to R and trying to get my head around some of the plots.

I'm trying to display which words are most occurring from a data frame which has a column for the word itself then a "count" column for the number of occurrences. Would it be possible to create a word-cloud plot with this information? From what I've only found guides on using raw text, which I don't have access to.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you post a sample of data as _text_ rather than an image. I had to pass the image you posted last time through OCR software to extract the data. Also, for word cloud generation, letters are going to look terrible. Could you please make up an example data frame with words instead of letters and post the actual text? Store your made up data frame as `df` then call `dput(df)`- the output of that function will give you a string you can copy into your question to make it reproducible for folks here.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to get a word cloud with data in this format. I have had to create a dummy data frame based on the format you show in your image (see below), but the code is just:

```r
library(wordcloud2)

wordcloud2(spamwordcountdf)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
spamwordcountdf <- structure(list(word = c(
  "Unsecured debt", "Enlargement", "Money", 
"Valium", "Viagra", "Vicodin", "Weight loss", "Opportunity", 
"Xanax", "Bank", "Warning", "Suspicious", "Act now", "Don't delay", 
"Wonderful"), count = c(151062L, 109878L, 105425L, 103997L, 100761L, 
90840L, 89645L, 83720L, 58852L, 54181L, 47605L, 44695L, 42336L, 
38793L, 36867L)), row.names = c("41", "55", "7", "139", "15", 
"276", "174", "24", "73", "141", "46", "228", "242", "78", "130"
), class = "data.frame")

spamwordcountdf
#>               word  count
#> 41  Unsecured debt 151062
#> 55     Enlargement 109878
#> 7            Money 105425
#> 139         Valium 103997
#> 15          Viagra 100761
#> 276        Vicodin  90840
#> 174    Weight loss  89645
#> 24     Opportunity  83720
#> 73           Xanax  58852
#> 141           Bank  54181
#> 46         Warning  47605
#> 228     Suspicious  44695
#> 242        Act now  42336
#> 78     Don't delay  38793
#> 130      Wonderful  36867
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>